# Missing CGAL/hierarchy_simplify_point_set.h file in ubuntu install

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, cgal

I am trying to build some source code on ubuntu 16.04 where one of the classes relies `hierarchy_simplify_point_set.h` header file, which is part of CGAL's point set package. After following instruction on the installation page, I have installed `libcgal-dev` and `libcgal-qt5-dev` via `apt-get`. The package manager has installed `libcgal-dev 4.7` which should include the point set library. However, the particular header file seems to be missing (it seems to have some files from the point set library and not others - I am looking in `/usr/include/CGAL`). Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

ps: For good measure, I have already tried uninstalling and reinstalling both the packages, but no luck.

Comment: Is upgrading to a newer Ubuntu version an option for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This header has been introduced in CGAL 4.8 while it seems you are using CGAL 4.7.

You can get the latest version of CGAL [here](https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/releases). Since the latest versions can be used as a header-only library, simply extract the release archive somewhere and set `CGAL_DIR` to that location when calling cmake to configure your example and it should work directly.